# Why can't I "import datetime" before "from scapy.all import *" in python3?

Tags: python, datetime, import, scapy

OK, maybe i'm missing something totally obvious, but it seems that I cannot import datetime BEFORE I import "from scapy.all import *". It works fine if I import datetime AFTER I import "from scapy.all import *". I don't understand this.

Example; This does NOT work...

```
    #!/usr/bin/env python3
    import os
    import datetime
    from scapy.all import *
    current_time = datetime.datetime.now()
    print(current_time)
```

But THIS does...

```
    #!/usr/bin/env python3
    import os
    from scapy.all import *
    import datetime
    current_time = datetime.datetime.now()
    print(current_time)
```

I'm using Arch Linux, Python3 and the latest scapy.

Comment: Please elaborate on "does NOT work". What actually happens? Do you get an error message? If you do, post it (including full stack trace).

Comment: The answer below makes sense. But in case it might help others I'm going to post the error; AttributeError: type object 'datetime.datetime' has no attribute 'datetime'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just a guess comparing your two snippets, but I suspect you have a **[namespace clash](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/what-are-python-namespaces-and-why-are-they-needed--cms-28598)** (welcome to the joys of programming) and that's precisely why `import *` is bad practice.

`scapy` has a `datetime` method too (haven't compared the definition between the two packages), so in this context the **import order** does matter because the definition of `datetime` is **overridden**.

The best would be to import just what you need eg:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import os
import datetime
from scapy.all import sr, srp
current_time = datetime.datetime.now()
print(current_time)
```

Comment: Specifically, `scapy.all` exports `datetime.datetime`, so `datetime` would be the class, not the module, in the OP's problematic code.

Comment: This is also why generally the use of `import *` is not recommended :p To be more precise you should even do `from scapy.sendrecv import sr, srp` rather than use `scapy.all`